# Norm squared inequality

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, optimization, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, triangle-inequality

I am reading a paper in optimization and confused about the following identity: Let $a,b,c$ be elements of a real Hilbert space $H$,

$$
\|a-b\|^2 \leq 2\|a-c\|^2 + 2\|c-b\|^2.
$$

At first I thought it was just the triangle inequality and adding/subtracting $c$ inside the the first norm. However, since we have the norm squared instead of norm I am not sure that's the case. Can the inequality be true as stated?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> At first I thought it was just the triangle inequality and adding/subtracting $c$ inside the the first norm.

That, and then from the obtained

$$\lVert a-b\rVert^2 \leqslant \lVert a-c\rVert^2 + 2\lVert a-c\rVert\cdot\lVert c-b\rVert + \lVert c-b\rVert^2$$

we conclude using the inequality

$$2uv \leqslant u^2 + v^2$$

for $u, v \in \mathbb{R}$, following from $(u-v)^2 \geqslant 0$.

Comment: @DanielFischer is there a name for this inequality (2nd equation in the answer)?

Comment: @Zim I'm not aware of a special name for particularly this one, but it's an instance of the AM-GM inequality (if we assume $u,v \geqslant 0$ or take the modulus on the left hand side).

Answer (score 1):

We can you also C-S here:
$$2||a-c||^2+2||c-b||^2=(1^2+1^2)\left(||a-c||^2+||c-b||^2\right)\geq$$
$$\geq\left(||a-c||+||c-b||\right)^2\geq||a-c+c-b||^2=||a-b||^2.$$

Comment: The step where you distribute the square power, how is that justified? It's not always true that $(x+y)^2 \leq x^2+y^2$? (example: $x=y=1/2$)

Comment: I used $2(x^2+y^2)\geq(x+y)^2$. See please better my solution. I used the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Comment: It's not clear to me where CS is used.

Comment: C-S it's the following: $(a_1^2+a_2^2+...+a_n^2)(b_1^2+b_2^2+...+b_n^2)\geq(a_1b_1+a_2b_2+...+a_nb_n)^2$. In our case $n=2$. We obtain: $2(x^2+y^2)=(1^2+1^2)(x^2+y^2)\geq(1\cdot x+1\cdot y)^2=(x+y)^2.$