# Example of a strongly convex function where the Lipschitz constant $L$ is equal to the strong convexity parameter $u$

Tags: convex-analysis, examples-counterexamples, lipschitz-functions

I am trying to come up with like three strongly convex function $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ where the Lipschitz constant $L$ is equal to the strong convexity parameter $u$, i.e. for every $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$
\begin{align}
|\nabla f(x)-\nabla f(y)|&\leq L|x-y|, \tag{1}\\
 f(\cdot)-\dfrac{u}{2}|\cdot|^2&\;\;\text{is convex, and} \tag{2}\\
L=u \tag{3}
\end{align}

I am having a hard time coming up with such functions but I am suspecting that a type of least square might possess the property. Can someone help me come up with such functions where $L=u$? Thanks.

Comment: Strongly convex

Comment: What are the domain and codomain of your function? Usually a Lipschitz operator goes from a space to itself, but strong convexity is a property of a function from a space to $\mathbb{R}$. So are you assuming this operator maps from $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Yes that is right

Answer (score 0):

It holds for $f(\mathbf{x})=\frac{1}{2}\|\mathbf{x}\|_2^2$, which has a strong convexity and L-smoothness parameter $1$ w.r.t the $l_2$ norm.

We derive this from the Conjugate Correspondence Theorem which states that a $\mu$-strongly convex function has a conjugate $f^*$ which is $\frac{1}{\mu}$-smooth. Since we have the "rare" occasion where $\frac{1}{2}\|\mathbf{x}\|_2^2$ is it's own conjugate, with the parameter $1=1^{-1}$, the two coincide.

Comment: Set $x=3$, $y=0$, then $|f(x)-f(y)|=4.5 > 3 = | x-y|$ so $f$ is not 1-Lipschitz. I think the constant is actually $2$, see e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2617575/norm-squared-inequality

Comment: @Zim you're confusing a Lipschitz function with Lipschitz gradient. The gradient of $\frac{1}{2} x^2 = x$. Then in your example, $3\leq 1*3$. Q.E.D :)

Comment: I agree its *gradient* is $1$-Lipschitz, but it looks to me like the OP was asking for a strongly convex Lipschitz-continuous *function*; they did not mention $L$-smoothness at all.

Comment: @Zim you got me there. Since strong convexity and $L$-smoothness are related I might have read it wrong. But we'll need to wait and hear from him.